# If $f:X\to X$, $f(f(x))=x$, is $f$ onto?

Tags: functions

I have been trying following question and was unable to solve.

> Let $f: X \to X$ such that $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x\in X. \space$ Then:

1. Is $f$ 1-1?
2. Is $f$ onto?

Clearly $f$ is 1-1 . But I am unable to deduce why $f$ must be onto or not.

Comment: Hint: for every $y\in X$, you're looking for an element $z\in X$ such that $f(\underline z)=y$. Does it help to use the assumption that $f(\underline{f(y)})=y$?

Comment: Such a function is called an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)).  As for surjectivity (*onto-ness*)... you just need to show that for each $x\in X$ there is some $y\in X$ such that $f(y)=x$ where such a $y$ might depend on $x$.  Clearly, letting $y=f(x)$ works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ were not onto, since $f:X\to X$, $f(X)\subset X$ and this containment is *proper*. Then $f(f(X))\subset f(X)\subset X$, but this contradicts $f(f(x))=x$ for every $x\in X$.

Answer (score 2):

If $z$ is an arbitrary element of $X$ then map it to get $f(z)$ which complies $f(f(z))=z$, so $f(z)$ is the preimage of $z$. Hence $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is its own inverse, so $f$ is bijective and in particular surjective.